# "Replace All" does nothing when using the "Replace in Selection" feature in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, find-replace

Replacing in selection is a crazy difficult process - and it apparently does not even work.  Getting to the point of even having `Replace in Selection` enabled we need to:

- highlight the area
- Hit Find  by Alt-Cmd-F

Then we can try to do replace in selection by:

- Hit Alt-Cmd-L

[image]

The replacement selections dialog is on the upper right . I have put in 'space' for the find and nothing/empty for the replacement.

[image]

How to replace all at one swoop?  Hovering for a while gives the nominal answer:

[image]

But CMD-Enter does *nothing.  Actually ENTER does nothing either. This Find in Selection is inoperative??

Comment: if you have an easier way of doing it in the GUI let VSC know

Comment: highlight an area. Hit Ctl-R (or whatever is bound to Replace), paste or type in pattern to replace, tab to the replace-with field, type it in ,  hit Alt-A (for replace-ALL). Done.  This is basically the approach for `JetBrains` IDE's and it takes < 5 seconds and I don't remove hands from keyboard

Comment: on non-Mac: select region `Ctrl-H` `Alt+L` type find text `TAB` type replace text `Ctrl+Alt+Enter`, what is that different from JetBrain, the difference is `Alt+L`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an additional step I found by trial and error: we need to tab to the Replace field and *then* hit CMD-ENTER.

This whole process is rather hard to believe about how cumbersome to do for a core/essential editing capbility.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue on Ubuntu. For me, the shortcut is `ctrl+alt+enter`, and I can use it with "Find in Selection" enabled, and the find field is focused instead of the replace field.

Comment: if you would look up the command bound to `CMD-ENTER` you find that `"when": "replaceActive && searchViewletVisible && !findWidgetVisible"`